# How can I synchronize contacts with Google?

Tags: iphone, mail.app, contacts, gmail

How can I download (also, possibly upload from my iPhone) contacts of my Google account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your iPhone, you can [set up an Exchange account](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?answer=138740&topic=14252), and enable Contacts synchronization.

Assuming you're on Mac OS X, you can also set up Google Synchronization with Address Book app and Contact synchronization with iTunes.

I've had issue with the former concerning the addresses, the city, postal code, etc. fields weren't correctly mapped. YMMV. On the plus side, the modification made to either Gmail or the iPhone are immediately applied to the other.

The second works fine for me, the downside is that you have to connect your iPhone to your computer when you want to share the modifications you made to the contacts.

Comment: I've had a lot of LastName/First name problems with this too. (As google has them "the other way around" and sometimes you get duplicates. Always keep a backup just in case something goes wrong and you have to start over.

Comment: You can also sync the Mac OS X address book with Google. Start the address book and go to Preferences → Accounts → On My Mac → Account Information and check "Sync with Google".

Comment: @Martin "this" is Google Sync via Exchange, via Address book or contacts sync in general?

Comment: @Loïc Good question… I disabled it since then, but I'm sure it was Address Book -> Accounts -> Sync with google. That caused a myriad of dupes. I even erased my google contacts and tried syncing again "from scratch" but something doesn't really work flawlessly and I decided it was not worth. I do have a google "exchange" for the emails in the iPhone (which actually works ok with push), but haven't tried (or don't remember trying) *that* contact sync (or the iTunes version)

Comment: @Martin, well, the iTunes version is the same as the Address Book version. At least, I think (I'll try to check tonight). So if it didn't work with Address Book, it might not work with iTunes for you. Then again, it depends when you tried it, I believe they made some change along the way. Like only syncing the "my contacts" part and not the entire directory.

Comment: In the "set up an Exchange account" link, on the last picture, it shows "mail, contacts, calendar", but mine shows "mails, calendar, notes". Also, actually, I have an iPod 4G (isn't it the same system?), and I use it with linux, not mac osx.

Comment: @Tom Are you sure you selected `Exchange`? If I recall correctly, "mails, calendar, notes" is when you use the `Gmail`-type account.

Comment: actually, I had set up this when I bought the device. If I cancel the configuration and go with `Exchange` what will change? Will I still be able to edit my calendar on both google and ipod, and have them synchronized?

Comment: @tom yes, the Exchange setup also allows you to edit your calendar

Comment: it worked fine =D

Comment: by the way, I thought I had lost my notes for a second, as they vanished from my ipod. But a brief search shows that they are on my gmail with the tag "Notes". I would like they still sync also.

Comment: @tom the only way for you to get the note back, is to create a `Gmail`-type account (name it "notes" or whatever) and only active the note part (not the caledar, nor the mails). Note sync is not available with the Exchange setup.

Comment: @Martin I completely agree with increasing redundancy backups up to a point. But don't forget google contacts already have a time machine backup for some time now. You can recover data on it from any given time. It's pretty remarkable.